# Hibernate Unidirectional @ManyToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relationship between accounts and groups. The data for the groups table comes pre-populated and there is no adding additional groups.

Using Hibernate, my desire is to:

1. Add an account to the account table,
2. Add a record to the account_group table, and
3. **NOT** add a record to the group table

It seems to me, no matter what I do, I always get a duplicate record in the group table. This is my problem. Here is my code:

*Account.java*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account", schema = "admin")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinTable(name = "account_grouping", schema = "admin", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "account_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "grouping_id"))
    private Set<Grouping> groupings;

...

    // getters and setters

}
```

*Grouping.java*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "grouping", schema = "admin")
public class Grouping {

...

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

...

    // getters and setters

}
```

*AccountDao.java*

```
@Repository
public class AccountDao extends AbstractJpaDao<Account, String> {

...

    @Transactional
    public boolean create(Account newAccount) {
        try {
            getEntityManager().merge(newAccount);
            return true;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Danger, Will Robinson!: " + e);
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

I have looked up many questions and websites regarding Hibernate @ManyToMany examples, but I must be missing something. Thank you for reading and for your help.

Comment: Why do you have a cascade for merge and persist, since you precisely do not want to ever add or update a new group? Remove that. Then post the code which actually creates an Account and adds groups to it, before saving it.

Comment: If I do not have any CascadeType specified it gives me the following error: ```Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance beforeQuery flushing```

Comment: I should have mentioned Jackson is serializing a JSON response from the front-end that becomes the newAccount variable above. The groupings variable in the JSON looks like this:
```groupings: [{name: "groupa", groupType: "typea"}]```

Comment: The error is quite a strong hint. It tells you: "you're saving a new, non-persistent group as part of the account". You precisely do NOT want that. By adding a cascade, you make Hibernate save this new group while saving the account. The correct way to deal with this error is to avoi passing a new group, and pass an existing one instead, which is what you want. Hibernate identifies entities using thei ID. The group you save in the account doesn't have any.

Comment: I feel stupid! That was it! I just needed to include the id of the group in the JSON response body sent to the back-end. Since you were the first to post a solution, if you post your solution as an answer, I will mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: MatMat had the same explanation in his anwer from the start. You should accept his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I do not have enough rep to make a comment, so I'll throw my guess as an answer. Make sure the Group entity has an ID when selecting a Group for your Account before saving your entity. Otherwise the Group entity is treated as a new Object and will be saved into the grouping table.